# How to make IE7 display this font style like other browser?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-7

How to make IE7 display this font style like other browser (IE8 , chrome ,FF) ?

i tired to do , thank for ans

```
<div style="
font-family: &quot;Brush Script MT&quot;, cursive;
font-size: 29px;
padding-top: 18px;
padding-left: 20px;
color: turquoise;
">
ABC DEF
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. If you are trying to *just make it work*, your question is too broad.

Comment: Maybe a fiddle would be good, so that then we can see what you are _trying_ to do.

Comment: Note that font rendering is notoriously different between browsers and operating systems. It is nearly impossible to get fonts to display exactly the same everywhere. Often, if it's a font used on something like a logo, sites will have an image of the desired font and use that instead of getting fonts to render exactly the same.

Comment: Thank i know issue , it's may be from install ie

Comment: When asking this kind of question, you should always specify what goes wrong. In this case, how does IE7 behave differently from other browsers. Does the text display at all, or does it have the wrong font, the wrong size or colour, etc. Or if the differences are hard to describe, include a screenshot. Then the issue is much better to diagnose.